# Collection.sort Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: java, mysql, sorting

I am trying to determine the order of columns in a MySQL database in Java. I have the create statement(this.create) of the table and the name of the columns (column.getName()). I then find the index of the column name in the create statement. I assign these values to a List, and then, I sort them using Collectio.sort(). This isthen used to determine the order of the columns. The only issue is that I am not getting the expected result. Here is my code:

```
 public void orderColumns() {

        List<Integer> cols = new ArrayList();
        for ( column column : columns ) {

            cols.add( this.create.indexOf( "`" + column.getName() + "`"));
        }

        Collections.sort( cols );

        for ( column column : columns ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
                if ( this.create.indexOf( "`" + column.getName() + "`") == cols.get( i )) {
                    this.order_of_columns.add( column );
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(this.create);
        for( column column : order_of_columns ) {

            System.out.println( this.name + " : " + this.create.indexOf( "`" + column.getName() + "`") + " " + column.getName());
        }
    }
```

Here is the output for one table:

```
CREATE TABLE `versions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `version` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
versions : 77 name
versions : 119 version
versions : 28 id
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I think it could be a problem with your for loops. Could you try: `for ( column c : columns )` instead of `for ( column column : columns ) `? I can't understand why the Java compiler would compile that!

Comment: What do you expected?

Comment: @cdaiga Because this is legal Java.  It keeps separate namespaces for different kinds of identifiers.  However, the convention is to use names starting with upper-case for classes, so `column` as a class name doesn't follow the convention.

Comment: I expect the integers to be in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sort` is working fine, but you're not actually using the order that the sort produced.  After the `sort`, here's what you do:

```
    for ( column column : columns ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
            if ( this.create.indexOf( "`" + column.getName() + "`") == cols.get( i )) {
                this.order_of_columns.add( column );
            }
        }
    }
```

That is, you go through the columns in the *original* order.  For each column, you go through `cols` to see if the `indexOf` result is in the `cols` array.  But for this purpose, the order of elements in the `cols` array won't matter, since all you're doing is checking to see whether the index is somewhere in that array.  You're actually adding things to `order_of_columns` in the same order that they appear in `columns`.  So you haven't rearranged anything, and your `sort` is useless.

However, if you go through `cols` first, then you'll be adding to `order_of_columns` based on the order in `cols`.  Therefore, I think that if you just switch the two `for`'s, you'll get the answer you want.

There are better ways to do this, though.  Your code is doing a lot of duplicate work by sorting just the integers, and then going through and figuring out what columns correspond to those integers--work you've already done.  Better would be to create a POJO class `ColumnAndIndex` that has an `Integer` and a `column`, and make it a `Comparable` class whose `compareTo()` compares just the integer (which will be the `indexOf` value).  Instead of a `List<Integer>`, create a `List<ColumnAndIndex>` that stores both the `column` and the index.  Use `sort` on that; that will sort on the indexes.  Now just go through the result, and the columns will already be there--no extra work needed.

Comment: Thank you. Reversing the order of the for loops did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
 public void orderColumns()
 {
    Map<Integer, Column> cols = new SortedMap<>();
    for ( Column column : columns )
    {
        cols.put( this.create.indexOf(  "`" + column.getName() + "`" ), column );
    }

    System.out.println( this.create );
    for( Map.Entry<Integer, Column> entry : cols )
    {
        System.out.printf( "%s: %d %s%n", this.name entry.getKey(),
                                          entry.getValue().getName() );
    }
}
```